# Mysql Update user Balance SQL syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I want update an Users Balance but i dont know how i can do it.
With my code its dont work:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE apiusers SET balance = balance - (product_price) WHERE username = (username);";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Table apiuser:

```
+-------------+
| Field       | 
+-------------+
| id          | 
| user        |
| pass        | 
| balance     |
| lastip      | 
| lastlogind  |
| email       |
| verification|
+-------------+
```

Comment: Please edit the question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: dont mix up insert and update.

Comment: please add some sample data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You forgot your equal

```
$sql = "UPDATE apiusers 
        SET balance = (balance - product_price)
        WHERE user = \"".$username."\";";
```

\"username\", because " would close the string for $sql and with \" you prevent that.

You need a "Where", so you can update the column with the ID xy.

Comment: Thanks i have Updated my Question, i just can request the Username, if i do this from you i get the same error or how can i insert the Value correct?

Comment: Do you want to Insert or Update?

Comment: If the User click the Buy button i want subtract the product price from his balance

Comment: Yes thats looks great:) , the last Problem is that this "username" dont work, i have this line in my Script: "$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['username']);"

Comment: Try my new edit, btw, do you have a SESSION with the username?

Comment: i request the Username from an form an site before. I get now this error: "WHERE username = "admin";. Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause'"....

Comment: Oh sorry, it's userid, not username, read that wrong, I'll edit that away

Comment: Hm i dont understand it, I get the same error: "WHERE userid = "admin";. Unknown column 'userid' in 'where clause'"

Comment: Could you put the columns of the table apiusers underneath your question?

Comment: Concatenating values into a query string like this makes you vulnerable to SQL injection. It is unsafe and should not be done this way. Use a correctly parametrized query.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect something like this:

```
update apiusers
    set balance = balance - ?   -- how much to change the balance
    where userid = ?;           -- which user to change it for
```

(Of course, I don't know how the users are identified.)

The `?` is for parameters to pass in with.  You should be using parameters, rather than stuffing the values into strings.